# Is it possible to send keys to browser without focusing on an interactive element in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm looking for a way to just get Selenium to type out a string on a browser window without focusing on any specific element. I couldn't find a way to get `send_keys` working without defining a driver so I tried defining a driver as a non-interactive part of the website. Unfortunately, when I try to run the code below, it produces a `Message: element not interactable` error. I'm assuming it's because Selenium is expecting an input field but is unable to find one at non-interactive element `[@class='inner-2pZNJ24z']`.

```
def screen(timeframe_count, wait):
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='inner-2pZNJ24z']")))  
    screen = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='inner-2pZNJ24z']")
    screen.send_keys(str(timeframe_count))
    screen.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Is this possible? I've tried using `pynput` but the input doesn't get forwarded to the browser.

Comment: Try sending the keys to the html or body tag.

Comment: I think you answered your own question, you do need an element to interact with. It might help if you could explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm not sure how else to explain it. When focused on the browser, but not focusing on any interactive element, typing on the keyboard sends the input to the webpage which is then processed by some unknown element. No specific element in element inspector reacts when this is done so I have no way to really identify which element I have to send the input to.

Comment: Well, you could try to select some root element of your browser window and then use JavaScript to send your input, this should bypass the execption. Something like this:

cmd = document.getElementByXPath('XPath').value = 'new value'
driver.execute_script(cmd)